# Does each Route include its Request and the Response returned by the Server?

Tags: haskell, happstack

For each `dir..` , it is a `Route` which takes in a `Request` and returns a `Response` created by the `Server`. I am wondering if the `Request` and the `Response` included in each line of the code. Thanks in advance!

```
simpleHTTP serverConf $ do
decodeBody (defaultBodyPolicy "/tmp/" 4096 4096 4096)
msum [ do
      nullDir
      seeOther "graph" (toResponse "Redirecting to /graph"),
      dir "grid" gridResponse,
      dir "graph" graphResponse,
      dir "image" graphImageResponse,
      dir "timetable-image" $ look "courses" >>= \x -> look "session" >>= timetableImageResponse x,
      dir "graph-fb" $ seeOther redirectUrlGraphEmail $ toResponse "",
      dir "post-fb" $ seeOther redirectUrlGraphPost $ toResponse "",
      dir "test" $ look "code" >>= getEmail,
      dir "test-post" $ look "code" >>= postToFacebook,
      dir "post" postResponse,
      dir "draw" drawResponse,
      dir "about" $ aboutResponse aboutContents,
      dir "privacy" $ privacyResponse privacyContents,
      dir "static" $ serveDirectory DisableBrowsing [] staticDir,
      dir "course" $ look "name" >>= retrieveCourse,
      dir "all-courses" $ liftIO allCourses,
      dir "graphs" $ liftIO queryGraphs,
      dir "course-info" $ look "dept" >>= courseInfo,
      dir "depts" $ liftIO deptList,
      dir "timesearch" searchResponse,
      dir "calendar" $ lookCookieValue "selected-lectures" >>= calendarResponse,
      dir "get-json-data" $ look "graphName" >>= \graphName -> liftIO $ getGraphJSON graphName,
      dir "loading" $ look "size" >>= loadingResponse,
      dir "save-json" $ look "jsonData" >>= \jsonStr -> look "nameData" >>= \nameStr -> liftIO $ saveGraphJSON jsonStr nameStr,
      notFoundResponse
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Perhaps this tutorial will help: https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/stepcut/the-happstack-crashcourse

Comment: I mean in each route, there supposed to be a request and a response. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each line is a *handler*. Think of a handler as a function which takes a request and returns a response.

`graphReponse` is a handler which handles the request in a certain way.

`dir` modifies the handler so that it doesn't get called unless the request url begins a certain way.

There is nothing special about having the word `Response` in the name of the handlers. `graphResponse` is just the name of a function - you can use any names for your handler functions.

What you have is a list of handlers, e.g.:

```
[ handler1,
  handler2,
  ...,
  notFoundResponse
]
```

When a request comes in a check is made to see if the `handler1` will handle the request. If not, `handler2` is checked and so on. If no handler accepts the request the `notFoundHandler` is called which will probably generated a 404 page.

That's why the `dir ...` part is important - it prevents a handler from responding unless the url begins a certain way.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much! I know there is nothing special about having the word 'Response' in the name of the handlers. However, I am wondering if we can use the name of the handler to stand for the response that returned by itself.

Comment: Just name your handlers however you want - the name of the handler doesn't matter. How about an up vote?

Comment: Thanks! I already did, but my reputation is still under 15. So the up vote I gave will remain unseen.